# How do I achieve the desired effect with the mirror modifier?

Tags: modeling, mirror

I'm trying to use the *Mirror* modifier to create a shape as shown below the cur Torus in the guide image floating below it,  but for the life of me, I cant get it to work

[image]

When I try to mirror it on the Y axis, the new mesh just overlaps with the existing one like so:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The object gets mirrored relative to it's *Origin point* (the little orange dot in the middle). To make the shape you want, you have to move the object in *Edit Mode* (this moves the object relative to its origin - in object mode the origin moves with the object when you move it). In your case, enter edit mode, select the whole mesh, and "drag it away" on the Y axis. Make sure to enable "merge" and "clipping" in the modifier panel

[image: Origin]

Comment: Thanks so much! Will try this right away.

Comment: This worked, Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy I could help ;)